# How does one access the Clarifai API for local file uploads in React?

Tags: reactjs, api, clarifai

This is my first question in Stack Overflow in my developer journey. In my project, I have implemented a file upload system which on clicking the button would trigger the Clarifai API recognition. Below is a snippet of my code where the thing is happening. Unfortunately, it seems to me that the `this.state.input` isn't updating in the right manner so that the API could respond. Any sort of help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

```
 handleImage = (e) => {
    this.setState({input: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])});
  }
  onButtonSmash = () => {
    this.setState({imageUrl: this.state.input});
    app.models.predict(Clarifai.CELEBRITY_MODEL, this.state.input)
      .then(response => this.setState({solution: response.outputs[0].data.regions[0].data.concepts})
      .catch(err => console.log(err)))
  } 
    <div>
      <input type="file" onChange={this.handleImage} />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you have initialized the API as such: https://github.com/Clarifai/clarifai-javascript#basic-use
- Make sure that onButtonSmashed is called (looks nested in your code snippet)

Comment: I have did that, sir. With image Url it works just fine. And onButtonSmashed is also called. The problem is that the api isn't taking a valid url input, this I found by console.log ing. So is there any other way we can create a url from a local file apart from this and base 64 method ? Thank you.

Comment: @NeellohitSenapati What error do you see in the console?